# MariaDB suddenly requiring database name prefixed to table name

Tags: mariadb

I'm new to MariaDB (and databases in general). I'm using MariaDB 10.5.9 on Windows 10 from terminal.

I'm not sure how/why, but for some reason MariaDB is requiring my `SQL` statements using table names to prefix the database name to the table name, even when I have specified 'use database_name' and the line shows `MariaDB [database_name]`.

So for example, this previously worked:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> use database_name;
Database changed
MariaDB [database_name]> ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN columnA int;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'columnA' at line 1
```

whereas now I must type:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> use database_name; 
Database changed 
MariaDB [database_name]> ALTER TABLE database_name.table_name ADD COLUMN columnA int;
```

I may be mistaken, but I'm 99% sure I didn't have to type the database name once I had specified `use database_name;` and all the help examples/resources don't include that.

This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32383700/is-it-important-to-write-database-name-before-table-name) is similar, where the answer indicates `use database_name;` prevents the need to attach the database to the table name (however I'm not using `SQL` keywords as column names).

Wondering if there's a setting that might change the need to always require the `database_name` prepended to `table_name`?

Any suggestions (including suggestions to improve my question) would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! Have you tried bouncing the server? It is weird - if you do the <use schema> command, then you shouldn't have to qualify the table names...

Comment: this is not the first time i read such a claim. Maybe it is a bug

Comment: The error message is not related to current database/schema. The query citate starts from the point where the problem is detected - and it is new column name `columnA` or a space before it (it is inherited from MySQL, and I hope that MariaDB developers have not broken this). Try simply to re-type the command completely, letter-by-letter, and none copy-paste.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. It's running locally on my laptop (so I just tried forcing shut down with the button). I also re-typed the syntax with no success. And when I re-type the syntax but prepend `database_name` to `table_name` it works. This is quite odd (and frustrating) I guess. I just couldn't find anything similar when searching for help.

Comment: Was your column really called `columnA`?  Or was it some _new_ reserved word, as in the bug mentioned?

Comment: It was not really `columnA`. I tested a few times with different column names while I was creating the table and it required the `database_name` (not the real database name) prepended to the `table_name` (also not the real name). But it needed the database name for other commands as well for changing existing column types, even showing columns in existing tables.

Comment: So now I'm really sure MariaDB suddenly started requiring the syntax `database_name.table_name` as I went back into some `R` code where I created a query and it just used the `table_name` and it worked before, but now it does not and I have to add `database_name.table_name` to the query.